# knockoutjs viewmodel not loading ajax return

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout and have been having trouble loading my ajax json return into a viewmodel.   I"m using the knockoutjs mapping plugin.

here is the json return:

```
{"operator":[{"employeeid":394,"Category":"mc","OpFirstName":"fred",
"OpSurname":"penner","RegNumber":"a12234","Status":"ft","SupervisorID":0,"Team":"a",
"TeamGroup":"a1","isSupervisor":"y"}]}
```

Here is my code:

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: OpviewModel.items">
    <tr>
        <td><ul>
                <li data-bind="text: OpFirstName"></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">


    function OpviewModel() {
        var self = this;

        $.getJSON("../controllers/GetAllOps.php", function (data) {
            OpviewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            console.log(data);

        });

    }

    ko.applyBindings(new OpviewModel());

</script>
```

The JSON is created by using PHP_ENCODE.  I've tried using just "foreach: operator" but still had no luck.  Any tips would be appreciated.
Any help would be great.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: OpviewModel.items">
```

should be

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: model.operator">
```

And this bit

```
$.getJSON("../controllers/GetAllOps.php", function (data) {
    OpviewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Should be

```
$.getJSON("../controllers/GetAllOps.php", function (data) {
    self.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

There were 4 problems,

1. You dont need to specify the model class name when binding
2. There is no property `items` on your viewmodel - you called it `model`
3. The model applied to `model` does not have a property `items`, the property is `operator` (according to your received json)
4. You tried adding a property to the definition of the model, not the instance of it.

Comment: I've tried that, now I get an error:

    TypeError: c is null
 ...(g),h(b,g,d)}function h(b,c,d){var e=!0,f=1===c.nodeType; f&&a.e.Kb(c);if(f&&d||a...

Comment: do I have to define model as a observable array??